# Conditionally change background color of column using formulas on style= attribute

Tags: visualforce, validation

I have the following statement for an object, I'm trying to use highlighted columns in a pageBlockTable according to a specific value, this page gets the value of the field and set a background color.

The field has no default value, but when I save the record and check the code again, the value of the last 4 values sets to the text "Cerrada". Any ideas why is happening?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Avance" >
    <apex:dataTable value="{!Recomendaciones__c}" var="RC" rowclasses="" align="center"  style="font-size:150%">
        <apex:column value="{!Recomendaciones__c.Avances__c}"
            style="{!IF(RC.Avances__c="Con avances significativos","background-color:#33FF33;",
        IF(RC.Avances__c="No hay avance","background-color:#00CCCC;",
        IF(RC.Avances__c="Avance mínimo","background-color:#FF6600;",
        IF(RC.Avances__c="Avance moderado","background-color:#FFCC33;",
        IF(RC.Avances__c="Cerrada","background-color:#FF0000;","")))))}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
 </apex:pageblocksection>
```

Comment: Two questions:  Does the color change apply to the entire column, or to individual cells of the table?  Also, I don't think the IF statement is evaluating the way you want it to.  Try something like style="background-color:{!IF(RC.Avances__c = "Text", '#7CFC00', '#FFA07A')}"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's a small table with only 2 cells, so I thought changing the color of the column would affect only the cell of the right. I tried to change the code to your suggestion, but this will set a color for any value different from the selected, with this statement. Could you please help me to set the other conditions or one more? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Do you rerender the portion after calling Save action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `style` If will recommend to use `StyleClass` attribute where you can define set of classes to change the look and feel. A Sample example:

```
<apex:column value="{!Recomendaciones__c.Avances__c}" 
styleClass="{!if(Record.Field__c == 'NULL' || Record.Field2__c == 'NULL','red',if(Record.Field__c != Record.Field2__c,'yellow',''))}" />
```

You can use same function with `style` attribute as well but there you have set in-line style instead of class name.